# How to access global variables from a custom code activity?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

Just getting started with WF4.

Ran into a problem with passing some text from a native code activity (located in the middle of a sequential workflow) onto the next (xaml-based) activity in a sequence.

Here is a quick synopsis: a custom native code activity makes a DB call and needs to pass the result to a standard "SendReplyToRecive" activity (which is the last activity in this workflow). There is a global variable "reportValue" defined at the top-level sequence level, but I'm struggling to get to it from within that custom native code activity.

The design surface for this workflow does not offer Arguments, just Variables and Imports, so, I'm not even sure if I could use OutArgument.

How is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your custom NativeActivity is defined to return a value, like this:

```
public sealed class MyCustomNativeActivity : NativeActivity<int>
{
    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        context.SetValue<int>(base.Result, 10);
    }
}
```

You should now be able to set the returned value to a Variable using *Result* property through the designer.

EDIT:

Check this sample image. In your MyCustomNativeActivity you'll have available a Result property. To assign the value returned to a variable just initialize that variable and put it in the Result field.

From that point on you can use that variable wherever you want.

Notice that in the sample MyCustomNativeActivity the returned value is an *Int32* but it can be any other type.

[Image link here](https://s4.postimage.org/gbr5mede1/nativeactivity.png)

[image: Example Image]

Comment: Thanks, Jota!I was trying to access the Result in the designer, but could not see it there. Is there a particular expression, that exposes the Result? Also, it looks like NativeActivity<ReportValue> is suggesting that ReportValue, which is just a global top-level variable, can be used as a type. Am I interpreting this correctly?

Comment: In *NativeActivity{ReportValue}*, ReportValue is the type returned by the activity. You can use any other type like *decimal*, *int* or whatever. For example if you use NativeActivity{string}, the Result will have the type *string*. Simple as that.

Comment: I can see how I can assign my data value to the Result, I just do not see how I could access Result from the standard "Assign" activity - Result does not show up in the list of available agruments.

Comment: Your doing it wrong. Initialize a variable through Variables tab. **The Result property is available on your CustomActivity**. You just have to put the variable name on the result field. Just like saying *fill this Variable with the result from my CustomActivity*

Comment: I have such variable - "ReportValue" Is there a particular VB expression to initialize the value of ReportValue with Result? This is my fourth day with WF - thus my ignorance :)

Comment: Check the edited answer above. If you aren't seeing the Result property when selecting your CustomNativeActivity on the designer it's because it isn't properly implemented to return a value.