# How do I access output arguments from Custom activities at design time in WWF4

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I'm building a VERY simple sequential workflow in WF4.  I have 3 sequential activities I created using the designer: ValidateName, ValidatePhoneNumber and ValidateAddress.   These all have an input argument: customer and and output argument: isValid.  All I'm trying to do is create a new activity (ValidateCustomer) composed of these 3 activities.  I want to take the boolean returned from each activity and assigned to some object that's the returned from the ValidateCustomer activity back to the workflow.  However, I want to do this from the designer.  Is this even possible?  I'm sure is something very simple I'm missing.

Thanks,

Buzz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create boolean variables, also through the designer, and assign them using the *Result* output from each custom activity. Then you can verify variables' values using other activities. In your particular case you may want to use *If*.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356544/how-to-access-global-variables-from-a-custom-code-activity/7365989#7365989)'s image. In that case the custom activity is returning an *int* but the  rule is the same.